# How to make a composite content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to create a content type that has some unique fields but its other fields are references to other existing nodes (not a parent-child relationship but many to many relationship).

I have looked in entity reference module or field collection? Is there another way of doing this?

For example I have a synthesis report made up of smaller topics. I want this report to have a name and author but then it needs to reference multiple of these smaller topics (which are a content type of their own).

I could maybe make a Taxonomy term for every synthesis report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. You can add fields to your content type which are a reference to other entities, like taxonomy terms, nodes, etc.

**Note**:  You can combine it with field collection, but you need to understand that a field collection is not the same thing. A field collection lets you group fields so you can re-used them. For instance if you have multiple addresses, you can create a field collection with street, zipcode, city, etc. But in itself, it's not an entity. Entity reference lets you point from one entity to another.

Comment: but I need a grouping and I don't know how many references there are. Can I combine it with field collection?

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to understand that a field collection is not the same thing. A field collection lets you group fields so you can re-used them. For instance if you have multiple addresses, you can create a field collection with street, zipcode, city, etc. But in itself, it's not an entity.

Entity reference lets you point from one entity to another.

Comment: @Web-Beest : please verify my edit of your answer (I mostly just integrated your comment in it). If needed, further edit your answer, or simply perform a rollback to the prior revision if you don't like my edit at all. Doei!

Answer (score 3):

You can use both [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, then you can add a Reference field (Node Reference if using References module) or Entity Reference (in case of using Entity Reference module) , and then **set the number of values for that field to 'Unlimited'** (if you don't know how many references is needed for each report exactly).

### [image: Heading]

PS. Entity References is more complicated to work with but it presents much better features in comparison by References Module.

Comment: If you need multiple value to be set for a certain field you don't need a field collection, the only option to change is to set the field number of values to unlimited.

Comment: ok I missed that! I voted for the answer the first one just because of timing, sorry